# Question about composition in the category $ \textbf{Rel} \ $

Tags: category-theory

I have a question concerning the composition of morphisms in the category $ \textbf{Rel} \ $.

First, for categories generally, it is frequently stated that if $ f \colon A \to B $ and $ g \colon B \to C $ , i.e., if cod(f) = dom (g), the morphisms must compose in order to fit the definition of a category.

However, the category  $ \textbf{Rel}\  $ seems to have an additional requirement for composition (or perhaps an additional requirement for being a valid category). $ \textbf{Rel}\ $ is of course the category of relations with sets as objects and where the morphism $ f \colon A \to B $  is a set $ R \subseteq A \times B $.  Similarly, the morphism $ g \colon B \to C $ is a set $ S \subseteq B \times C$ .

In this category the composition is given by $ S \circ R = \lbrace (a,c) \in A \times C \mid \exists b \mid ((a,b) \in R $ and $ (b,c) \in S ) \rbrace $.

My question concerns this composition.  Is it not longer correct to say that the composition will necessarily exist if cod(f) = dom(g)? Or does composition always exist if cod(f)=dom(g) but in this case we have an additional requirement so that the category will always make sense?  Also, to what extent can a null set in a situation like this be considered a valid composition?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what sort of additional requirement you might be thinking of here.

Comment: In answer to the last sentence - the null set is always a valid relation between any two sets.

Comment: Why do you think that the composition might not exist?  You've written down a perfectly good definition for it...

Comment: @Eric & Daniel - The set $ S \circ R $ could be empty, which would seem to imply that the composition is undefined.   Is that incorrect?

Comment: $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Rel}}(A, C)$ is the set of subsets of $A \times C$; and $\emptyset$ is a valid element of this set.

Comment: Likewise, even in $\mathbf{Sets}$, $\emptyset$ is a valid morphism $\emptyset \to A$ for any set $A$ (called the "empty function").

Comment: But you are correct to note that if you tried to define a category $\mathbf{RelNE}$ where the objects are sets, but the morphisms are *nonempty relations*, then the composition rule would not necessarily give a nonempty relation, so the attempted category definition would be invalid.  (Or to put it another way, $\mathbf{RelNE}$ is not a valid *subcategory* of $\mathbf{Rel}$ because the morphisms are not closed under composition.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all $A$ and $B$, the null set is indeed a subset of $A\times B$, so it fits the definition of a morphism $A\to B$. What else is there to say?

Answer (score 1):

The composite $S \circ R$ only exists when the codomain of $R$ is the domain<sup>1</sup> of $S$, where the words "composite", "domain", and "codomain" all refer to the category structure of **Rel**.

This does not preclude there being some other operation that extends the category composition operation to be defined for other possible products as wel.

---

In case it is a point of confusion, note that the domain of an arrow in **Rel** does not need to be the domain of the relation in the set-theoretic sense.

This is one point in favor of the alternate terminology of "source" and "target" for the corresponding category operations.